# Rectangle Boxes in PHP Code After Upload

Tags: php

I have these crazy rectangle boxes showing up in my PHP code after uploading them to my server. i've tried everything - changing transfer type on ftp, charsets, tried just emailing myself the files in rar to the server and downloading via email, still on my computer i have no rectangle boxes but once they hit the live server the rectangle boxes appear breaking my php code.

Comment: Post the code please! :)

Comment: Are you going from Windows to *nix, *nix to Windows, Mac to Windows? What is the character encoding of the editor you're using?

Comment: I can't post the box i'm seeing, as it doesn't appear to be a valid character, however they are all over my code, in every php file

Comment: I'm going from Windows to Windows - i've tried auto detect on char encoding as well as forcing utf8 - using filezilla to transfer

Comment: Open the files from the computer they originated from in notepad and go to File -> Save As. What encoding is listed at the bottom of the dialog that appears?

Comment: it appears on the problematic files they are showing ANSI - but also, on the computer where the files don't have their wierd box they are also showing as ANSI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like you have weird characters in your code. Sounds like you already did this, but double check that you are uploading using 'ascii' and that you are using appropriate characters. If it's a certain character that is breaking, maybe switch it out for another one. Also, make sure you are editing the files using a text editor and not something like word or writer. Hope that helps. (also, if you can show an example that would help tremendously =D )

Comment: Hello - i've tried uploading using ascii - i am using notepad to view the files, locally there is no box, notepad via the live server shows these wierd character boxes - unforutnately i can't post the code because the boxes aren't accepted as valid characters to be posted :(

Comment: How about saving it as UTF8 instead.

Comment: Only problem is i'm not sure how to resave all these php files in bulk, there are hundreds if not thousands